# How to get current application culture using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in

Without looking at the registry, is there a way to get the current application culture in C#?

I have a Add-in and want to get the language from the ArcMap hook using ArcObjects 10.

(I'm using C# to develop the addin.)

Comment: Better to be asked at www.Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Does `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` give you what you want? I'm not sure if there is a way with Arcobjects, or if it can differ from the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is what you are looking for:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0048000001s1000000

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

Comment: Dan Jurgella -  thanks for this. I'm going to test that is does pick on on the culture of Arcmap as the add-in runs.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment by @Dan Jurgella... Don't forget to check the properties in the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` class.  There are static properties in that class, `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`, which could help you.  Also depending on what you're doing with languages, it probably wouldn't hurt to be familiar with the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace and classes in case you are dealing with multiple character sets/encodings.